# what is the Difference between <> and != in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know:

```
>>> 1 != 2
True
```

and:

```
>>> 1 <> 2
True
```

but I don't know what the difference between `<>` and `!=`

Comment: Difference is probably that <> takes more operation and more time to check and thus is less concisely

Comment: @JediPythonClone no, it doesn't *"take more operation"*; do you think that `x <> y` is interpreted as `(x < y) and (x > y)`?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe perhaps I was mistaken, my apologies, that's why I said probably and left it as a comment, not as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<>` is removed from the language in Python3.
In Python2, they are the same, but `!=` is preferred.

Comment: oh yes. this is true. i test it now and see that <> is removed from python 3 and <> is an unknown syntax in python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they're interchangeable

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 interprets the two statements exactly the same (as NOTEQUAL). See [tokenizer.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/829b49cbd2e4b1d573470da79ca844b730120f3d/Parser/tokenizer.c#L1162).

**Also from docs:**

> `!=` can also be written `<>`, but this is an obsolete usage kept for backwards compatibility only. New code should always use `!=`.

(from https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#stdcomparisons)

**How I read these statements**

`1 != 2`: I read this as 1 is not equal to 2.

Knowing that python supports `1 < 2 < 3` to express inequalities, you can consider `<>` a shortcut for less than or greater than but not equal.

`1 <> 2`: I read this as 1 is less than 2 exclusive AND 1 is greater than 2 exclusive which happens to exclude the case x==y where x = y.

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, really, why is it not correct?

Comment: ...because what you've written doesn't match how the language works. `x <> y` is **not** interpreted as `(x < y) and (x > y)`.

Comment: sure - the language parses and interprets <> and != exactly the same. Edited to make it clear that is how `I` read the symbols.

Comment: But you still say *"They are equivalent in the statement you provided"*, suggesting that there are statements in which they aren't. And including chained comparisons seems completely irrelevant and bound to muddy the metaphorical waters.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - thanks for the help improving the answer.

Answer (score 0):

They have the same functionality. != is used by convention. The only reason <> still exists is for backward compatibility with older versions of Python.

Comment: Heres a reference -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 0):

It is the same.

See the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#stdcomparisons

> `!=` can also be written `<>`, but this is an obsolete usage kept for backwards compatibility only. New code should always use `!=`.